# Parsing Markdown using Marked in Laravel 8 and VueJS 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, laravel-8

I wonder if you are able to help me at all.

I'm attempting to build a forum using Laravel 8 and VueJS, however I've hit a brick wall where the Marked plugin doesn't seem to be working.

It does not convert the markdown to html, I think i'm using it correctly, but I may be wrong.

My Vue Component code is below

```
<template>
    <v-card
  elevation="2"
  outlined
  shaped
>
<v-container fluid>
<v-card-title>
    {{data.title}}
</v-card-title>
<v-card-subtitle>
    Posted By {{data.user}} {{data.created_at}}
</v-card-subtitle>
<v-spacer></v-spacer>
<v-card-text v-html="data.body"></v-card-text>
</v-container>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import marked from 'marked';

export default {
    props:['data'],
    computed:{
        body(){
            return marked.parse(this.data.body);
        }
    }

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I have tried defining it as a global import, however it still does not work.

It still displays the markdown instead of converting to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
<v-card-text v-html="data.body"></v-card-text>
```

with:

```
<v-card-text v-html="body"></v-card-text>
```

In your code, you are using `data`, which is the raw prop. But what you really want is to use the computed value `body`, which calls Marked.

You should avoid using properties with the same names (`data.body` and `body`) to avoid confusion. If you rename your computed from `body()` to `markedHtml()`, the code will be a lot easier to read.

You also didn't import Marked correctly, use this import:

```
import { marked } from 'marked';
```

Comment: Issue is, will this still display the data pulled from the database?

Comment: It will display the result of your computed: `marked.parse(this.data.body)`. So yes.

Comment: I've just tried this resolve, and it still doesn't parse the markdown

Comment: My solution will resolve your issue; check again that you did everything properly.

Comment: It's now telling me Marked is not defined

Comment: That's another issue; did you declare marked in your package.json? did you install it with npm or yarn?

Comment: It is declared in my package.json and i installed it with npm

Comment: I edited my answer based on Marked's documentation : https://marked.js.org/

Comment: That fixed it. I'm a dunce clearly.

Thank you for the help :)